# How to index list of documents with doc id in ElasticSearch NEST 7.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm indexing a list item with this code:

```
foreach (var menu in mappedCollection)
        {
            var response = await client.IndexAsync(menu, i => i.Id(menu.OptomasToolId));
        }
```

How to make IndexMany or any equivalent call so that I can index many items in one shot with their Ids.

Comment: You mean bulk index ?

Comment: Yes. But with document id.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/indexing-documents.html#_multiple_documents_with_bulkallobservable_helper

Comment: Thanks! it works with BulkAll. how to handle its completion and error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the low level API elasticsearch.net to bulk indexing many documents specifying index and id.

see : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net-getting-started.html#_bulk_indexing

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way:

```
 BulkAllObservable<MenuForElasticSearch> bulk = client.BulkAll(mappedCollection, b => b
          .BufferToBulk((descriptor, list) =>
          {
              foreach (var item in list)
              {
                  descriptor.Index<MenuForElasticSearch>(bi => bi
                      .Index(index)
                      .Id(item.OptomasToolId)
                      .Document(item)
                  );
              }
          }));
         bulk.Subscribe(new BulkAllObserver(
             onError: (e) => {
                 // TO DO;
             },
             onCompleted: () => { 
                 // TO DO;
             }
         ));
```